# Python Make List of List for Row Data

Tags: python, arrays

I want to append rows in Google Shread Sheet using append_rows(rowData) like below-

```
rowData = [
    ['44', 'Data44', 'My Data'],
    ['45', 'Some Data', 'My Data']
    ]
worksheet.append_rows(rowData) # Rows Will be appended at last row of sheet
```

It works well.

But how I populate rowData dinamically in a for loop like below -

Tried

```
rowData = []

for i in range (1, 3):
    moreRowData = [i, 'Data 'f'{i}', 'My Data 'f'{i}']
    rowData.extend(moreRowData)

print(rowData)
```

It not working. I am new and unable to figureout the thing to make it working.

Comment: `rowData.append(moreRowData)`? you need to explain what *not working* means.

Comment: The rowDara should be like 

`rowData = [['44', 'Data44', 'My Data'], ['45', 'Some Data', 'My Data']]`

Comment: Use `append` instead of `extend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rowData is a 2-dimensional list containing  the rows. When you use `rowData.extend(moreRowData)` All the values are added just as elements of the list rowData. But we need to add lists of rows in to rowData so that it becomes a 2-dimensional list.So, append each list into the rowData. (Note: If you use f-string in the following way, it will be easy to understand)

```
rowData = []

for i in range (1, 3):
    moreRowData = [f'{i}, Data {i}, My data {i}']
    rowData.append(moreRowData)

print(rowData)
```